# how to deal with include_once php urls?

Tags: php, include-once

I'm building a static site and trying to get a bit modular on the code. Using include_once solves my problem, but the new created section.php file is seen as another URL on the server and IMHO creates a SEO problem - duplicate content. Thin theory, but still.
Is there any solution to use include_once and mark those included files as non-existent for crawlers?

Just a code example, to better define what the problem is.

**index.php looks like this:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php include_once ('header.php'); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Page content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**header.php looks like this:**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**So generated code will render like this:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Page content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

header.php is another file on the server and could be indexed by search engine, because it has its own URL. Question might be dumb and may have the simplest answer, I just don't know if I should use redirects or some other tweaks.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about using the identical header on different sites, that doesn't count to the actual content.

Comment: thanks, sounds fair.... as i said, is a thin theory

Comment: For security alone you should hide your source files outside of the web directory, (httpdocs, http_public, web),  Only the bootstrap (index.php) and frontend assets need be visible to anyone outside.  Even then, ìndex.php should be disguised as index.html, just to help keeping them guessing.

Comment: So I should put those file outside public_html? In the root of my webserver? Would that generate some path issues? If my root stucture looks like this: root/public_html/DOMAIN/index.php, I should keep those files in the root and include them with <?php include_once ('../../header.php'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by multiple ways.

1. Add a Robots.txt file
2. In your included file add a key variable for authentication.

**1- Robots.txt:**
Save this as Robots.txt in your website's root directory.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /elements
```

Save your files in elements folder. Whatever will be in elements folder, Google and other search engines's Crawler will not crawl it. This will never list in search results.

**2- Use Key Authentication** 
**index.php will looks like this:**

>

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <?php $key = 'allow_this'; ?>
    <?php include_once ('header.php'); ?>
     <div id="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
         <p>Page content</p>
     </div> </div>
```

**header.php looks like this:**

```
<?php if($key=='allow_this'){ ?>
<div id="header">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I should take a look on $key then. See how it works, then maybe implement it. Thank you.